# What is the temperature inside the International Space Station?

Tags: iss, temperature

What is the temperature inside the ISS? How is the temperature regulated?
I have seen a few clips of the ISS and the crew was wearing just T-shirts and shorts, so the temperature must be normal.

Comment: Here's the answer [straight from the horse's mouth](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2001/ast21mar_1/). Don't be afraid to use google next time.